# Is it possible to enter kufr because of bad thoughts about Allah?

Tags: kufr, waswasa, evil-thoughts

Lately, horrible thoughts about Allah have started popping into my head that are even scary to say. At any moment, my voice may appear in my head insulting Allah. These thoughts cause me great pain and I sometimes think that I will enter kufr because of them.

I am afraid that this is seen as a mockery of Allah and that it takes me out of the religion. What should I do in such a situation? Am I out of the religion because of these thoughts?

Comment: do my answer here answer your query https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/80355/no-shaitan-no-worry

Answer (score 1):

> What should I do in such a situation?

You are suffering from waswas and it's okay, you will have to find a treatment for it (let it be ruqyah, therapy or whatever suits you).

> Am I out of the religion because of these thoughts?

No. Actually some Ulama believe such fears are good signs of being faithful, some people told the Prophet once that they are suffering in their minds from extremly grave things, the Prophet told them their fear is "the pure faith" ([sahih](https://sunnah.com/muslim:132a)).

> It is narrated on the authority of Abu Huraira that some people from
> amongst the Companions of the Apostle (ﷺ) came to him and said:
>
> Verily we [find] in our minds that which every one of us considers
> it too grave to express. He (the Holy Prophet) said: Do you really
> find such things? They said: Yes. Upon this he remarked: That is the pure faith.

Imam Al-Nawawi commented on that hadith saying:

> It means: Your horror in saying it is pure faith. If this is
> grave, and there is intense fear of it, and of uttering it, in
> let alone believing in it, it is only for the one who has completely and
> truly achieved faith, and is free of suspicion and doubts.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The thing is that I am beginning to think that all these bad words against Allah in my head are spoken by me personally, and not by shaitan whispering to me about it. It's scary.

Answer (score -1):

Asalam alikum
Brother/sister
These are only thoughts you didn't do anything so don't worry you didn't sin
Even if you sinned repent and go back to Allah(swt) he is the most forgiving most merciful.
For something to count as a sin
A action must have been done but your thoughts aren't sins