# Thoughts that I worship not Allah

Tags: shirk, kufr

It all started with the fact that during prayer and at other times I have terrible thoughts in my head. Namely, I see images of Allah. I realize that I should not do this, but I cannot get rid of these thoughts. I feel that I am committing kufr. Recently, while praying, I had the idiotic thought that I was worshipping my classmate. I quickly told myself that I was only worshipping Allah, however I am afraid that I have indeed committed kufr. What should I do in this situation and have I really committed kufr/shirk?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bad thoughts about Allah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/80654/bad-thoughts-about-allah)

Comment: @lr0 Unfortunately, that doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score -1):

No you haven’t committed kufr. These thoughts are from shaitaan. Al-Bukhaari (5269) and Muslim (127) also narrated from Abu Hurayrah (may Allah be pleased with him), that the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “Allah, may He be glorified and exalted, will forgive my ummah for whatever crosses their minds so long as they do not act upon it or speak of it.” Try your best to get rid of these thoughts.